# $uibModal.open is not a function in karma (AngularJS Factory)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, karma-runner

I am trying to test a function that opens a `$uibmodal`. This is my factory function.

```
confirmationMessage: function (message) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'views/templates/utilsTemplates/confirmationMessage.html',
      backdrop: 'static',
      controller: function () {
        var messageCtrlVM = this;
        // message to show
        messageCtrlVM.message = message;
        // when yes_button is pressed
        messageCtrlVM.yesPress = function () {
          modalInstance.close(true);
        };
        // when no_button is pressed
        messageCtrlVM.noPress = function () {
          modalInstance.close();
        };
      },
      controllerAs: "messageCtrlVM"
    });
    return modalInstance.result;
  },
```

In its unit testing file, I am first adding provider for it like so.

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ui.bootstrap'));

beforeEach(function () {
    module(function ($provide) {
      $provide.value('$uibModal', function (value) {
        return value;
      });
    });
  });
```

After that I am injecting `open`, `dismiss` and `close` functions with `beforeEach` like so.

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_utilsFactory_, _$httpBackend_, _$filter_) {
  utilsService = _utilsFactory_;
  $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  filter = _$filter_;
  uibModal = {
    open: function () {},
    dismiss: function () {},
    close: function () {}
  };

}));
```

Finally I am trying to run my unit test by calling factory function.

```
it('should show a confirmation message', function () {
  var spy = spyOn(uibModal, "open").and.callFake(function () {
    return {
      result: {
        then: function () {}
      }
    };
  });
  utilsService.confirmationMessage("Are you Sure?");
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```

It gives me error that **`$uibModal.open` is not a function**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `beforeEach` should be like this:

```
beforeEach(module('myApp', function ($provide) {

    mockModal = {
        result: {
            then: function(confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
                this.confirmCallback = confirmCallback;
                this.cancelCallback = cancelCallback;
                return this;
            }
        },
        opened: {
            then: function (confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
                this.confirmCallback = confirmCallback;
                this.cancelCallback = cancelCallback;
                return this;
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            this.opened.confirmCallback(); // covers opened.then success
            this.result.confirmCallback(); // covers result.then success
            this.result.cancelCallback(); // covers result.then error
        },
        open: function (object1) {
            return this;
        }
    };
    $provide.value('$uibModal', mockModal);
}));
```

Note that, here, **the object which we are providing as `$uibModal` has the `open` function.** Having this passed in `$provide`, you would need to `callThrough` (not `callFake` after spying)

Feel free to remove `result` / `opened` / `close` if you are not using them here. They are useful when you have corresponding code.

Comment: Now, how to test if modal is opened or not? In "it" function.